# Alter table to add foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have the table `users` with the following columns:

```
| id | user_name | display_name | password | email |
```

I need to create a second table `uc_user_network` using the foreign key `user_name` from the `users` table.

```
| id | graphname | networkid | user_name |
```

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE uc_user_network
(
   ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   GraphName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   networkid varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
   FOREIGN KEY (user_name) REFERENCES uc_users(user_name)
)

ALTER TABLE uc_users
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users
    FOREIGN KEY (user_name)
    REFERENCES uc_user_network(user_name)
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: `User_Name` column is it Primary Key in the users Table ???

Comment: It's never a good idea to have a value driven column as a primary or foreign key. What happens if the username changes at some point? It's a good practice to use auto-generated IDs for this purpose...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE uc_user_network
(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),   --<-- Auto Increment is Identity 
GraphName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
user_name [DataType],     --<-- you need to create this column in this table 1st
networkid varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
FOREIGN KEY (user_name) REFERENCES users(user_name) --<-- Column Name in Users Table.
)                ^                   ^
     Column name in this table        This is the tablename
```

The Referenced Column must be Primary key in the Referenced table. Also The DataType of User_Name in this table should match the datatype of User_Name in Users Table.